# Ajax URL error unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="../JQUERY/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
function getOptions()
{
    var html=new String();

    $.ajax(
    {  
        //url: 'http://server.com/?method=get&search=menu_group_options_with_items&type=group&group_id=6&format=json', 
        url: 'http://server.com',
        data:
        {
            'method': 'get',
            'search': 'menu_group_options_with_items',
            'type': 'group',
            'place_id': '6',
            'format': 'json'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) 
        { 
            alert("function");
            //var data = JSON.parse(data);
            var h=new String();
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                h+='<div class="data">';

                h+=data[i]['group_option'].OptionsID+'<br>';
                h+=data[i]['group_option'].MenuGroupID+'<br>';
                h+=data[i]['group_option'].group_options_name+'<br>';
                h+=data[i]['group_option'].menu_group_option_information+'<br>';
                h+=data[i]['group_option'].menu_group_option_min_selected+'<br>';
                h+=data[i]['group_option'].menu_group_option_max_selected+'<br>';
                h+=data[i]['group_option'].fDateAdded+'<br><br><br>';

                for(var iter = 0; iter < data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'].length; iter++)
                {

                    h+=data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'][iter]['item'].OptionItemID+'<br>';
                    h+=data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'][iter]['item'].menu_item_option_name+'<br>';
                    h+=data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'][iter]['item'].menu_item_option_additional_cost+'<br>';
                    h+='<br><br><br>';
                }   
                h += '</div>';
            }
            alert("h");
            alert(h);   
            alert("html equals ");
            html=h; 
            alert(html);

        }

    });
    alert("returning html");
    alert(html);
    return html;
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var str="";
    str=getOptions();
    $('#content').append(str);  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I would run this using the full URL nothing would happen. I wouldn't get any information back. Now that I've changed my URL just to `http://server.com` and set the `data:{}` to the requirements from the URL, I still get nothing. At this point I'm stuck and don't know where else do go.

My Questions:

1. What would be a reason my code isn't working?
2. What else do I need to do to retrieve data from the website?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: according to jQuery, cross-domain posting and jsonp do not support synchronous operation. ref - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . have you checked this operation out with fiddler?

Comment: that jsonp was a mistake that you caught by accident!
it is not in the new updated code which still doesn't work

Comment: @SLaks what do you mean i can't do that? What can't i do?

Answer (score 0):

`async:false` is deprecated after jQuery 1.8. Either use older jQuery version change your code.

To change your code, move this part into the success function:

```
$('#content').append(str);
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks

```
function getOptions()
{

$.ajax(
{ 
    url: 'http://server.com/',
    data: 
    { 
        'method': 'get',
        'search': 'menu_group_options_with_items',
        'type': 'group',
        'place_id': '6',
        'format': 'json'
    }, 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) 
    { 
        alert("function");
        //var data = JSON.parse(data);
        var h=new String();
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            h+='<div class="data">';

            h+=data[i]['group_option'].OptionsID+'<br>';
            h+=data[i]['group_option'].MenuGroupID+'<br>';
            h+=data[i]['group_option'].group_options_name+'<br>';
            h+=data[i]['group_option'].menu_group_option_information+'<br>';
            h+=data[i]['group_option'].menu_group_option_min_selected+'<br>';
            h+=data[i]['group_option'].menu_group_option_max_selected+'<br>';
            h+=data[i]['group_option'].fDateAdded+'<br><br><br>';

            for(var iter = 0; iter < data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'].length; iter++)
            {

                h+=data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'][iter]['item'].OptionItemID+'<br>';
                h+=data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'][iter]['item'].menu_item_option_name+'<br>';
                h+=data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'][iter]['item'].menu_item_option_additional_cost+'<br>';
                h+='<br><br><br>';
            }   
            h += '</div>';
        }
        alert("h");
        alert(h);   
        alert("html equals ");
        html=h; 
        alert(html);

        $('#content').append(html);  
    }

});
alert("returning html");
alert(html);}
```

Comment: it's not that its setting the information to the div content. It's just got getting past the url in my ajax call

Comment: are you doing cross domain ajax call?

Comment: yeah that what im doing or atleast trying to do

Comment: If your response is Json, then just use jQuery.getJSON()
Here is the link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I've done that with previous attempts and none seem to work with .getJSON

Comment: what exactly is the error, try fiddler or firebug to check ajax requests?

Comment: The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page. is the error i get

Comment: thats related to firebug not this script.

Comment: then i don't get an error and im still back to where i was